# Don't understand why I can't exec a commandline binary in tclsh

Tags: exec, tcl, tclsh

Context: Windows 7, ActiveState Tcl 8.6.1

```
% info tclversion
8.6
% info patchlevel
8.6.1
```

I have a C# console mode app called SETCFG.EXE. It's on the path in C:\BIN.

```
% set project corp
corp
% set method Recent
Recent
% exec -- [list c:/bin/setcfg.exe bobat.cfg inserter.${project}.Method $method]
couldn't execute "c:\bin\setcfg.exe bobat.cfg inserter.corp.Method Recent": no such file or directory
```

Now it could be that I'm not specifying the tcl code correctly -- it has been many years since the last encounter -- so I'll try execing a string

```
% exec -- "c:/bin/setcfg.exe bobat.cfg inserter.${project}.Method $method"
couldn't execute "c:\bin\setcfg.exe bobat.cfg inserter.corp.Method Recent": no such file or directory
```

Hmmm ... maybe I need to put the program first and the parameters second ...

```
% exec -- "c:/bin/setcfg.exe" "bobat.cfg inserter.${project}.Method $method"
Syntax:
        c:\bin\setcfg.exe cfg sym val
child process exited abnormally
```

Parameters in a list?

```
% exec -- "c:/bin/setcfg.exe" [list bobat.cfg inserter.${project}.Method $method]
Syntax:
        c:\bin\setcfg.exe cfg sym val
child process exited abnormally
```

So what am I not doing right? I've tried a few possibilities. Are there yet more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify several args to `exec`, not a single arg. You want

```
exec -- c:/bin/setcfg.exe  bobat.cfg  inserter.${project}.Method  $method
```

Sometimes, you'll see code that constructs the command as a list. In that case, you will use the "splat" operator to expand the list into individual elements.

```
set command [list c:/bin/setcfg.exe bobat.cfg inserter.${project}.Method $method]
exec -- {*}$command
```

See the [exec man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) and the [Tcl syntax page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)